# How to get addresses if we give latitude and longitude using location API in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, reverse-geocoding

I have an application where I try to get address of a location based on the latitude,longitude coordinates.When I try to print all the address of particular coordinates , I am getting only single address. IS there any way to get the list of all addresses for the coordinates supplied . My code snippet is as below:

Where locationLatitude,locationLongitude are of type String which are converted to doubles. Address is a class which has getters and setters methods for getting details of state,city,country etc.

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(locationLatitude),
Double.parseDouble(locationLongitude), 1);
StringBuffer  addressAsString  = new StringBuffer("");
if(!addresses.isEmpty()){
    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        addressAsString.append(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n");
    return addressAsString.toString();
}
```

Comment: this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649401/how-to-get-addresses-if-we-give-latitude-and-longitude-using-location-api-in-andr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all your addresses,and change the third parameterof getFromLocation to 10 instead of 1 to fetch all 10 surrounding locations at the given geo point:

```
List addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(Double .parseDouble(locationLatitude), Double.parseDouble(locationLongitude), 10); 

for (Address addr:List addresses) {

  for (int i = 0; i < addr.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
  // your previous code here
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is, its not appending State or country, sometimes the city comes and sometimes it doesn. what's this behavior?